# Converting Sencha Touch 2.3 app to native android - cordova - APK size too big for even small app

Tags: cordova, extjs, sencha-touch, apk

I am converting a Sencha Touch 2.3 app to native android via Sencha Cmd (which integrates with Cordova)

I am following this guide : http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/guide/cordova

I already have a working Sencha Touch 2.3 app, made via Sencha Architect 3.0.4

1. I switch to the directory of the app, and do `sencha codova init com.example.VoltClient`
2. In the cordova.local.properties that was generated in my root folder, I change the following line to android only as I have only android platform. `cordova.platforms= android`
3. Run `sencha app build native`
4. I am never told precisely where the .apk file is made, so I usually search the entire folder structure, and find the apk inside `\cordova\platforms\android\ant-build`
5. It usually has two files of the name `VoltClient-debug-unaligned.apk` and `VoltClient-debug.apk`. Both are of the same exact size, and I copy one of them to my phone using the USB connection, and install it on my phone for it to work

THe last two points, I have sort of figured out on my own, I didnt read in a guide.
My questions are:

1. Is there a better way of doing this? Is it documented somewhere - surely there would be clear path where the apk is generated rather than me having to search deep inside the folders
2. Even for a simple app like : http://ezcodes.co.uk/som/New/VoltClient/, the size of the apk is 9 Mb. I think it is because it is the debug version? The sencha doc above says:

> For Cordova and PhoneGap, Sencha Cmd can only create DEBUG versions of
>   applications, not a Release (for an app store) version. To create
>   release versions, you have to use a packager such as Eclipse or
>   IntelliJ for Android, or Xcode for iOS.

Not sure if this is causing the huge size. How do I get the apk made for the production mode exactly then?

The full tree structure after all commands above have been executed:

```
+---.idea
|   \---scopes
+---.sencha
|   \---app
|       \---microloader
+---app
|   +---controller
|   +---form
|   +---model
|   +---store
|   \---view
+---cordova
|   +---hooks
|   +---merges
|   |   \---android
|   +---platforms
|   |   \---android
|   |       +---ant-build
|   |       |   +---classes
|   |       |   |   \---com
|   |       |   |       \---example
|   |       |   |           \---VoltClient
|   |       |   +---dexedLibs
|   |       |   \---res
|   |       |       +---drawable
|   |       |       +---drawable-hdpi
|   |       |       +---drawable-land-hdpi
|   |       |       +---drawable-land-ldpi
|   |       |       +---drawable-land-mdpi
|   |       |       +---drawable-land-xhdpi
|   |       |       +---drawable-ldpi
|   |       |       +---drawable-mdpi
|   |       |       +---drawable-port-hdpi
|   |       |       +---drawable-port-ldpi
|   |       |       +---drawable-port-mdpi
|   |       |       +---drawable-port-xhdpi
|   |       |       \---drawable-xhdpi
|   |       +---ant-gen
|   |       |   \---com
|   |       |       \---example
|   |       |           \---VoltClient
|   |       +---assets
|   |       |   \---www
|   |       |       +---css
|   |       |       +---img
|   |       |       +---js
|   |       |       +---resources
|   |       |       |   +---icons
|   |       |       |   +---images
|   |       |       |   \---startup
|   |       |       \---theme
|   |       +---cordova
|   |       |   +---lib
|   |       |   \---node_modules
|   |       |       +---.bin
|   |       |       +---q
|   |       |       |   \---benchmark
|   |       |       \---shelljs
|   |       |           +---bin
|   |       |           +---scripts
|   |       |           \---src
|   |       +---CordovaLib
|   |       |   +---ant-build
|   |       |   |   +---classes
|   |       |   |   |   +---com
|   |       |   |   |   |   \---squareup
|   |       |   |   |   |       \---okhttp
|   |       |   |   |   |           \---internal
|   |       |   |   |   |               +---http
|   |       |   |   |   |               +---spdy
|   |       |   |   |   |               \---tls
|   |       |   |   |   \---org
|   |       |   |   |       \---apache
|   |       |   |   |           \---cordova
|   |       |   |   +---dexedLibs
|   |       |   |   \---res
|   |       |   +---ant-gen
|   |       |   |   \---org
|   |       |   |       \---apache
|   |       |   |           \---cordova
|   |       |   +---libs
|   |       |   +---res
|   |       |   \---src
|   |       |       +---com
|   |       |       |   \---squareup
|   |       |       |       \---okhttp
|   |       |       |           \---internal
|   |       |       |               +---http
|   |       |       |               +---spdy
|   |       |       |               \---tls
|   |       |       \---org
|   |       |           \---apache
|   |       |               \---cordova
|   |       +---libs
|   |       +---platform_www
|   |       +---res
|   |       |   +---drawable
|   |       |   +---drawable-hdpi
|   |       |   +---drawable-land-hdpi
|   |       |   +---drawable-land-ldpi
|   |       |   +---drawable-land-mdpi
|   |       |   +---drawable-land-xhdpi
|   |       |   +---drawable-ldpi
|   |       |   +---drawable-mdpi
|   |       |   +---drawable-port-hdpi
|   |       |   +---drawable-port-ldpi
|   |       |   +---drawable-port-mdpi
|   |       |   +---drawable-port-xhdpi
|   |       |   +---drawable-xhdpi
|   |       |   +---values
|   |       |   \---xml
|   |       \---src
|   |           \---com
|   |               \---example
|   |                   \---VoltClient
|   +---plugins
|   \---www
|       +---css
|       +---img
|       +---js
|       +---resources
|       |   +---icons
|       |   +---images
|       |   \---startup
|       \---theme
+---metadata
|   +---model
|   +---resource
|   +---store
|   \---view
+---resources
|   +---css
|   +---icons
|   +---images
|   +---loading
|   +---sass
|   |   +---.sass-cache
|   |   |   +---128e2f4b7bfb52ef384e374a251b71c4ed994d1c
|   |   |   +---1c90655657c13be250810a284b256e926a36f9ad
|   |   |   +---1ca11a694f0b1071784db4b3a6dc5c561d02ad96
|   |   |   +---2149f8d1cff68ae50966d109d49e5bfd6ec50b87
|   |   |   +---26954d5c8e55ac3bd8222141337cc59b952459a6
|   |   |   +---279ab5d4b42dd71492319bcd9caca63a5d28bacd
|   |   |   +---30787d83a5940c773f32724589a33a79199bf405
|   |   |   +---378536102e0b73788a9cd2bf787960f166383aa7
|   |   |   +---3c7241d239eba3c20b65a3daf4174b64c081f54d
|   |   |   +---51ce3f03e8818d38cc42f53732b4618131a9ab33
|   |   |   +---522379a84a54aea10b6821f00c9173913b6ab0b3
|   |   |   +---57d21c61c610471ef03b1c7975454ca452fdaa26
|   |   |   +---5ec579f78865b41c4143289e4364fef35aca2a10
|   |   |   +---66a64d32d52ee0e936ddea50b1dc1750f3287990
|   |   |   +---6d9e23cd4b3bc55c522d33d4516a496ce2f86b23
|   |   |   +---705637c440eb6322a3053b2084996bf756dd0fdd
|   |   |   +---7afa3863269e15003f4e1528984de383cca7c3a6
|   |   |   +---82e87c1b8ec0434b72287ae13c9b8720bf6a1f0c
|   |   |   +---8589547fddf6a94058d2bad624f186a142e79908
|   |   |   +---87a785e527b59eb9e8746c2879bc20d719dba6e1
|   |   |   +---8f26403ce3864783eef211ff7cfc1b756725f7a6
|   |   |   +---986ef6cd01f988ea18f143744f9596917b7ff023
|   |   |   +---9a4e9e37ff410b8559b7032fdf2a2b01b92ad5de
|   |   |   +---9ddcde549ab9acfe48a1af668d860160d5083649
|   |   |   +---a4af9db75db35edb5d5815076c39c58ef85610dc
|   |   |   +---a8214bd2e70d414d1d440a13bd779c75e939c661
|   |   |   +---ac7e763099095338226601527d4a9e423e9203c6
|   |   |   +---ae00a9696b0fd54caae0735f3b21ec6c2898fb98
|   |   |   +---b1c045ce6fdfb70e41c16a5f1dd67c75d6fb0f67
|   |   |   +---c7f5e1b996d360126e09d5f7b1b319965d1001d4
|   |   |   +---cb543128af5e938d2c77d439bef5d9906c5c0d19
|   |   |   +---ce583be6fb6ac9ab54c7a886ca228bdd76425f39
|   |   |   +---d12ce068c41538684b3ec41b734ec2d37d4fbdff
|   |   |   +---d3320726b935ba02c131fb4825bf5ce9fb8d4c37
|   |   |   +---e0daee8ac2d8621ed6e605142d164c9db8030e60
|   |   |   +---e10ea657008d073a457ba004dc3d4ee9021de521
|   |   |   +---e1ebefb092489f6d5e8f75f569ad010f023a1605
|   |   |   +---e6a653f42365227e3a2a59b78a353636d079fad4
|   |   |   +---ecdf2a97d80583712352aba7087965e7692b212c
|   |   |   +---edc26d9b4af330029b8b069299e690590c89ebf3
|   |   |   +---ee94d0a1a3463e2e2de3d7cb4984b2e6f5c59c11
|   |   |   +---f86ba89140925eb449fbe4a2d41f039fd8979632
|   |   |   +---fa44f5c33d577f2cf0028637f60b60725addb0ec
|   |   |   \---fab609f96e03eba36dc28555020aa96610876df6
|   |   \---stylesheets
|   |       \---fonts
|   |           +---ios7
|   |           +---pictos
|   |           \---tizen
|   \---startup
\---theme
```

Contents of the root folder are here :

```
.architect
.idea
.sencha
app
app.js
app.json
app.json.meta
bootstrap.js
bootstrap.json
build.xml
cordova
cordova.local.properties
dir.txt
feed_section_ipsum_json.txt
home_page_feed_data.json
index.html
metadata
packager.json
packager.temp.json
resources
test.json
theme
tree.txt
user_data.json
voltclient.xds
```

Comment: For an app like what you have shared, the apk can never take 9mb. Something is going wrong for sure. You can do one thing, delete all the files and folders inside the "build" file of your sencha app and repeat the steps.

Comment: it's beacuse of cordova's default splashscreen and icon images,remove or replace them with your images hope it'll solve your issue :-)

Comment: dowjones123, were you able to find an answer to this? It's very relevant to me as I'm at the same spot. I've built and submitted the iOS app to the App Store. I have tested the debug.apk version on my android device but now need to build for production.